# MapReduce and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, view, mapreduce

I need to get users likes & comments on each news. Have this query:

```
comments_map = function() {
    emit(this.path, {"user" : this.user, "comment_date" : this.date, "comment" : this.text});
};

likes_map = function() {
    emit(this.path, {"user" : this.vote.user, "like" : this.vote.like});
};

r = function(key, values) {
    var result = {
        "path" : "",
        "user" : "",
        "comment_date" : "",
        "like" : ""
    }
    values.forEach(function(value){
        if(value.path !== null) {
            result.path = value.path;
        }
        if(value.user !== null) {
            result.user = value.user;
        }
        if(value.comment_date !== null) {
            result.comment_date = value.comment_date;
        }
        if(value.comment !== null) {
            result.comment = value.comment;
        }
        if(value.like !== null) {
            result.like = value.like;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

res = db.comments.mapReduce(comments_map, r, {out : {reduce : 'joined'}});
res = db.likes.mapReduce(likes_map, r, {out : {reduce : 'joined'}});
```

All done, but i cant' get normal results... All looks like on the picture:

[image]

How can i get pretty read result?

Comment: Show a sample of the original document and what you want to have results look like. Text and **not** a screenshot. It looks like you are running two mapReduce operations and I'd bet you don't need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So. This was easy... we just need to type after own query `db.joined.find();`